# Display Date in reverse order (d,m,y)?

Tags: php, date

I'm retrieving only dates from database from a DATETIME column named Date.

Using DATE(Date) I get just the date in this order: `2012-02-19`

```
SELECT DATE(Date)

echo $row['Day'];
```

How can I echo the date, day first, then month and last year. (As it's commonly ordered in Spanish)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Convert the date from the SQL into a PHP date and then use the `date()` function:

```
echo date("d-m-Y",strtotime($row['Day']));
```

Comment: Thanks ! It works perfectly ! Not only for SQL it works for normal date strings also !

Comment: be sure to set you timezone: date_default_timezone_set()

Answer (score 1):

Specify your new format to `date` function like this:

```
echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime($row['Day']));
```